# Network communication between Docker images

Tags: docker

I have 2 applications:

- server that binds on 127.0.0.1:5150
- client that connects to 127.0.0.1:5150

Each application is containerized in a Docker image. In the server Dockerfile I use:

```
...
EXPOSE 5150
...
```

I'm having trouble connecting to the server from the client:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --name server my-registry.com/server:0.0.1
$ docker run --rm -it --name client --link server:chat my-registry.com/client:0.0.1
```

I get connection refused.

Also telnet:

```
$ docker run --rm -it --name client --link server:chat --entrypoint=/bin/bash my-registry.com/client:0.0.1
root@f384b008ce68:/# env | grep CHAT_PORT
CHAT_PORT_5150_TCP_ADDR=172.17.0.54
CHAT_PORT_5150_TCP_PROTO=tcp
CHAT_PORT_5150_TCP=tcp://172.17.0.54:5150
CHAT_PORT_5150_TCP_PORT=5150
CHAT_PORT=tcp://172.17.0.54:5150
root@f384b008ce68:/# telnet $CHAT_PORT_5150_TCP_ADDR $CHAT_PORT_5150_TCP_PORT
Trying 172.17.0.54...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each docker container runs in a separate "network namespace".  The means that (a) each container has its own ip address and (b) `localhost` means "this container", and doesn't have anything to do with `localhost` in an other container.

If you want your services to be accessible from another container, you will need to configure them to *not* bind to localhost, and then access them using:

- the container ip, or
- the container name, when using `--link`, or
- some sort of service discovery mechanism, or
- publishing the ports on your host and accessing them via your host ip

Note that the `EXPOSE` directory is basically a no-op; containers running on the same host have, by default, unrestricted access to each other.  Using `EXPOSE` does aid in service discovery when you use `--link` because it will result in populating environment variables in the linked container with information about the available services.

For more information:

- https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#connect-with-the-linking-system